# xCode says "FlateDecode: decoding error." and on iOS8 or later, it crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

I'm creating a PDF reader app.

When calling CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, sourcePDFPage);, xCode reports "FlateDecode: decoding error.".

On iOS7, even I have this error, I can extract each page of original PDF to a single PDF page.

But on iOS8 or later, the app crashes at this point.

Would anybody kindly help me?

Thank you in advance.

My codes are below.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSString *fromPath = [location path];
    NSString *docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"download.pdf"];
    downloadDestinationPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSError *error;
     NSFileManager   *fileManage = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // ファイル削除
    if( [fileManage fileExistsAtPath:downloadDestinationPath])
    {
     NSError *error = nil;
    [fileManage removeItemAtPath:downloadDestinationPath error:&error];
}
BOOL copyResult = [fileManage copyItemAtPath:fromPath toPath:downloadDestinationPath error:&error];
if( copyResult ) {
    CFStringRef fullPathEscaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                          (__bridge CFStringRef)downloadDestinationPath, NULL,     NULL,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFURLRef    pdfURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, fullPathEscaped, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, NO);

    document_ = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
    // ページ数取得
    size_t  num = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages( document_ );
    _pageNumber = num;
    _documentPath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:docDir];

     for( int i = 1; i <=num; i++)
    {
        NSString    *pdfFileName = [docDir stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Page%d.pdf", i];
        // ファイル削除
            if( [fileManage fileExistsAtPath:pdfFileName])
            {
                NSError *error = nil;
                [fileManage removeItemAtPath:pdfFileName error:&error];
            }
            CGPDFPageRef    sourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document_, i);
            CGPDFPageRetain(sourcePDFPage);
            CGRect  sourceRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(sourcePDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, sourceRect, nil);
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            CGContextRef    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, sourceRect.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, sourcePDFPage);
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
            CGPDFPageRelease(sourcePDFPage);
        }

        CFRelease( pdfURL );
        pdfURL = NULL;
        CFRelease(fullPathEscaped);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(document_);
        fullPathEscaped = NULL;
        [_delegate didLoadPDF];
}
```

Comment: Decoding a PDF should typically not crash an application, even if the data cannot be decoded properly. So (1) there may be an error in that PDF (which gets handled transparently by the older iOS kit), and (2) Apple messed something up in the newer version. Possible solution: fix the PDF.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
PDF has no problem as the app can show pages on iOS7.
The crash occurs only on iOS8 or later.

Comment: What I meant is that it is possible there is an error in iOS 7 as well but it gets suppressed or fixed in the background. Can you share a PDF that works on 7 and fails on 8? Inspecting it may result in more than plain guesswork.

Comment: Thank you for your kind helps.
Here's a link to the PDF,[link](https://www.prime-kobo.com/download.pdf)
Hope this helps.

And let me ask one more question. How can I maintain the links in original PDF after separating to each pages?

Comment: I disabled the breakpoint for "All Exceptions!" then it works on iOS8.
And I got an error message"DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory."
I think I should solve this error. But I have no idea...